# Spring Security 3 - where is CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm in the middle of migration application from Spring Security 2 to 3 and previously the was used `CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON` in xml configuration, but in Spring Security 3 I don't see `FilterInvocationDefinitionSourceEditor` class and this directive.
Should I just remove it or is it still needed and there is some alternative?
I want to make a sure about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LowerCase was removed because [Request Matcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/RequestMatcher.html) encapsulate this behaviour. You should use it for  matching incoming request with predefined pattern.